# Can I view or export or clear Siri's interaction history?

Tags: ipad, siri, ios, history

I would like to ask you is it possible to somehow access all of Siri's history to view it or delete it?

Comment: I edited your question to make it better. "View or delete it." is not a sentence, so I combined it with the previous sentence to make a whole thought. I removed the "Thank you in advance" because that sort of stuff just clutters up the site and provides no benefit. On Stack Exchange sites, we thank the answerers by upvoting and accepting answers, which I see you did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from the privacy file displayed when turning Siri on - off.

> You may choose to turn off Siri or Dictation at any time. To turn off Siri, open Settings on your iOS device, tap General, tap Siri, and slide the Siri switch to “off”. To turn off Dictation, open Settings, tap General, tap Keyboard, and slide the Enable Dictation switch to “off”.  If you turn off both Siri and Dictation, Apple will delete your User Data, as well as your recent voice input data. Older voice input data that has been disassociated from you may be retained for a period of time to generally improve Siri, Dictation and dictation functionality in other Apple products and services. This voice input data may include audio files and transcripts of what you said, related diagnostic data, such as hardware and operating system specifications and performance statistics, and the approximate location of your device at the time the request was made.

Answer (score 7):

No there is no way to access Siri history. If any of it is stored, it will be stored anonymously as chunks of different words and phrases on Apple’s servers for better voice recognition.

Answer (score 3):

You can delete your Siri data from Apple's servers by disabling Siri in Settings.

Go to **General** → Siri and disable Siri.

This will delete your history with it. You can enable it again in the future with no problem.

Comment: This seems to be correct that when you disable Siri, it also send a signal to Apple deleting your anonymized input on their servers.

Comment: Now hang on a second. If the input is anonymized, how do they know what to delete when you disable Siri?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little script that'll save all new Siri recordings on macOS: https://gist.github.com/varenc/8cae8f19fede79f63b84cc85f602f382

It just uses `fswatch` to monitor the Siri directory looking for new recordings. Siri temporarily saves these on disks, but then immediately deletes them after upload. That script just copies that out before Siri can delete them. It lets you keep a record of all your Siri interactions, though it's just your audio, not Siri's responses.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't or at least I didn't find any answer. However, if it was questions to ask her on internet, check the Safari history, there will be all your searches through Siri.

Answer (score -1):

U can only check recent questions press home to access Siri swipe down !!!

Comment: Or if you don't have a home button, activate Siri for example by saying "hey siri" and then swipe down.

Answer (score -3):

First close and then restart Siri

Comment: How can a user restart Siri on a non-jailbroken iPhone? And how does this allow acccess to Siri's history?

Answer (score -3):

finding songs that you had siri identify for you. go into itunes on your phone, click the top right box. click on the siri tab.  this is with OS8

Answer (score -4):

Here is a way to view history. Hope this helps.

[View Siri history](https://discussions.apple.com/message/20519754#20519754)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you provide more information? When you just link to another post, that thread could move, or be removed altogether. At SE, we prefer answers to be largely independent.

Comment: By the way, @Arthur was asking for history - not the general questions you can ask Siri.

Comment: Sadly nothing in the linked discussion seems relevant...

Comment: The link tells the reader to press the 'i' in the Siri to see the history of all commands. This is false, the 'i' only shows examples on how to user Siri.